# MySQL subquery referencing a table outside it's scope

Tags: mysql

In the following query I'm receiving

```
Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'PRF.user_id' in 'where clause'
```

This is due to the fact that the subquery is attempting to reference PRF.user_id which is outside it's own scope. How can I rewrite the query in order to overcome this issue?

```
SELECT user_id, lastname,  
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM Demo_Orders_M 
        WHERE DemoOrderStatus = 253
        AND DemoOrderDate BETWEEN '2015-06-19' AND '2015-06-26' 
        AND `User` = PRF.user_id
        GROUP BY CustomerID, `User` 
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
    ) t1 
) recycling
FROM tbl_profiles PRF 
JOIN tbl_users U ON PRF.user_id = U.id 
WHERE PRF.user_id IN ( SELECT a.user_id FROM tbl_profiles a WHERE a.user_id IN ('1210', '789') ) 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Can you post a few rows of sample data and expected results, or make an SQL Fiddle? It would be easier to rewrite the query if users could see what you are trying to accomplish. I suspect there is more going on here, as you have `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` in a subquery without any aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I've noticed is that your subquery has a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause without any aggregate functions, which shouldn't be the case. It looks to me that what you are trying to accomplish is getting the `COUNT(*)` of demo orders for each user/customer combination. You can write that individual query like this:

```
SELECT customerID, user, COUNT(*) AS numOrders
FROM demo_orders_m 
WHERE demoOrderStatus = 253 AND demoOrderDate BETWEEN '2015-06-19' AND '2015-06-26'
GROUP BY customerID, user
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This is a simple aggregation query that will pull the number of orders each user has that meet the given criteria, and as long as they have two or more orders.

Then, you can join these results to your users table to get other info about those users. One thing to note about your query also is that you don't need to write an extra select statement that pulls the user ids like that, what you've written is redundant. The whole condition can be rewritten as:

```
WHERE PRF.user_id IN(1210, 789)
```

So, the final query would be as follows. Note that I used a `LEFT JOIN` and the coalesce function to make sure a zero value is returned for users who didn't meet the order criteria, and as a result were not returned by the subquery:

```
SELECT user_id, lastname, COALESCE(numOrders, 0) AS numOrders
FROM tbl_profiles PRF
JOIN tbl_users U ON U.id = PRF.user_id
LEFT JOIN(
   SELECT customerID, user, COUNT(*) AS numOrders
   FROM demo_orders_m 
   WHERE demoOrderStatus = 253 AND demoOrderDate BETWEEN '2015-06-19' AND '2015-06-26'
   GROUP BY customerID, user
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) TMP ON TMP.user = U.id AND TMP.user IN (1210, 789);
```

Comment: The HAVING COUNT(*) is an aggregate function. Without going into too much detail, I'm attempting to count the number of records in DemoOrdersM for which User and CustomerID match (GROUP BY)and at the same time, their combination occurs more than once (HAVING COUNT(*) > 1).

Comment: @bikey77 customer is never used in the outer query. Your outer query is based on user, not user/customer, so as I said underneath the question, I think something else may be going on here though. I can edit my answer, but typically your group by columns should appear in the select clause, as I'm about to edit. `SELECT * ... GROUP BY..` is not a good practice.